# How to define headers in spreadsheet to get gsx$title attribute in JSON response from google spreadsheet API?

Tags: json, google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am planning to use Google spreadsheet API to fetch data from a spreadsheet and render it in my mobile app using Sencha Touch. I have seen few blogs and tutorial which explain how to fetch and parse data but when I am trying the same I am not getting column wise data as attributes in `entry` object instead I am getting comma separated data in `content` tag.

To give you an example, here is sample spreadsheet in which I have change headers and data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkEOCoTxRKgvdDRZUnViSFlOVUF0QUJybkZ6VlBwTkE#gid=0

and here is its feed:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AkEOCoTxRKgvdDRZUnViSFlOVUF0QUJybkZ6VlBwTkE/od6/public/values?alt=json

but when I created same spreadsheet by hand from scratch I am not getting `gsx$name` & `gsx$processedlinkurl` attribute in JSON. Here is that sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgduEz3vmQUTdHZlSEI4bjN6VnZ5TVpRMFlyOVAtR0E#gid=0

Here is the JSON:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AgduEz3vmQUTdHZlSEI4bjN6VnZ5TVpRMFlyOVAtR0E/od6/public/basic?alt=json

To mark first row as header I have frozen first row in my sheet still JSON is not giving me header wise data in JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I got the mistake, it is **values** instead of **basic** which is to be used in URL while accessing spreadsheet API to get all headers in result which means

Correct URL:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AgduEz3vmQUTdHZlSEI4bjN6VnZ5TVpRMFlyOVAtR0E/od6/public/**values**?alt=json

Wrong URL:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AgduEz3vmQUTdHZlSEI4bjN6VnZ5TVpRMFlyOVAtR0E/od6/public/**basic**?alt=json

Comment: this is not working anymore The Sheets v3 API has been turned down.